# Can you play sound in windows while doing another task simultaneously?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, label

Is there a way to while playing winsound.PlaySound("some sound", FLAGS) also change a photolabel?  I've been trying and no matter where I put the play sound it always play the sound before changing my photo label.

My code:

```
def thriller(self):
    winsound.PlaySound("thriller.wav", winsound.SND_NODEFAULT)
    img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('thriller.jpg'))
    self.photoLabel.configure(image = img5)
    self.photoLabel.image = img5
    self.original_board()

def original_board(self):
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    self.image = Image.open("board.jpg")
    self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
    self.photoLabel.after(5000, lambda:    self.photoLabel.configure(image=self.photo))
```

Comment: I also have a bunch of other photo labels that also temporarily change then revert to original board after 5 seconds depending on whether some game action arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to play the sound asynchronly. The flag **winsound.SND_ASYNC** should do the work. If that does not help, you can spawn the winsound function in a new thread (or in python better a new process) such that it is played at the same time as the image changes.

Good luck!